# Failed to compile tex in r markdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown, miktex

I wanna make use of an R markdown and I get this message when I run `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_book")`:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Documentation.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output Documentation.tex --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-35~1.3\library\RMARKD~1\rmd\latex\DEFAUL~3.TEX" --number-sections --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --wrap preserve --variable "compact-title:yes" --variable tables=yes --standalone 
Error: Failed to compile Documentation.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
Please delete Documentation.md after you finish debugging the error.
```

I guess it's because it is not possible to install Miktex and I don't know why. Even if I run as administrator, if I choose the option to install only for me, as soon as the installation finishes, I get this error message

`Administrator mode cannot be enabled (makes no sense) because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup.`

If I choose to install for all users, it cannot finish the installation and I get this error :

```
initializing setup service...
starting installer...
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: C:\Users\yo\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mik32886
visiting repository C:\Users\yo\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mik32886...
repository type: local package repository
loading package repository manifest...
package repository digest: 4fedb4887b9f440cb2cbe754ef191951
going to install 10619 file(s) (214 package(s))
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from asymptote.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-spanish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from biber-windows-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex8bit.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex8bit-polish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from chktex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cweb.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cyrillic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from etex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from etex-pkg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontname.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ghostscript.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-cfg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-def.tar.lzma...
extracting files from gsftopk.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from knuth-lib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from knuth-local.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from makeindex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo-font.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mfware.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-asymptote-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-autosp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-axohelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bzip2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cairo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-chktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-console-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-curl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-devnag-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvisvgm-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-epstopdf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-etex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-expat-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fmt-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freeglut-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fribidixetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gd-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphite2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gregorio-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-harfbuzz-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-harftex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-jpeg-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-kpathsea-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lacheck-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-libressl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-log4cxx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua53-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lzma-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-m-tx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mkfntmap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpfr-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpmcli-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mspack-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pixman-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-png-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-popt-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-posix-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-qt5-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tdsutil-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex2xindy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ttf2pk2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ucrt-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-uriparser-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc140-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xindy-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zlib-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zzip-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from multirow.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ncntrsbk.cab...
extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from palatino.cab...
extracting files from pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from plain.tar.lzma...
extracting files from polyglossia.tar.lzma...
extracting files from poppler.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pslatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psnfss.cab...
extracting files from pstricks.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psutils.tar.lzma...
extracting files from rsfs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ruhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tex-ini-files.tar.lzma...
extracting files from texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from thumbpdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from times.cab...
extracting files from tools.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ttf2pk.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ukrhyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from unicode-data.tar.lzma...
extracting files from utopia.cab...
extracting files from xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xgreek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xindy.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xkeyval.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xltxtra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xunicode.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xypic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
extracting files from zerohyph.tar.lzma...
updating package manifests ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini")...
installed 3558 package manifests
visiting repository C:\Users\yo\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mik32886...
repository type: local package repository
loading package repository manifest...
initexmf "--common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin "--log-file=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:
Option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:

  Option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup.

An error occurred:
  source file: 
  source line: 0
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I cannot help with MikTeX installation. However, I have found TinyTeX easy to install, in particular on Windows and for usage with R via the `tinytex` package.

Comment: I have already done `install.packages("tinytex")` and restarted rstudio , but i get the same error

Comment: You need `tinytex::install_tinytex()` to actually install the `TinyTeX` distribution.

Comment: @RalfStubner you make an answer with your comment. Then hopefully joasa will mark it correct. This Q is definitely popular and your comment(answer) works.

Comment: @JohnPolo Thanks for the heads-up. It always amazes me which comments and answers get popular in the end.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need `tinytex::install_tinytex()` to actually install the `TinyTeX` distribution.